# how to solve non linear equation Pass two list of values to SciPy fsolve argument

Tags: python, list, scipy-optimize

I have the following function:

[image: function with respective variables]

```py
    from optimize import fsolve
    import numpy as np
    T = np.array([137,145,150,152,159,160,184])
    Di =np.array([1,0,1,1,1,0,1])
    r = 5.0

    def lnL(P):
        mu, sigma = P
        return -r*np.log(sigma)-(1/2)*np.sum(Di*((T-mu)/sigma)**2)+np.sum(1-Di)

    sol = fsolve(lnL, (15.0,258.0))
    sol
```

And I am getting this error:

```
fsolve: there is a mismatch between the input and output shape of the 'func' argument 'lnL'.Shape should be (2,) but it is (1,).
```

Comment: `mu, sigma P` this is invalid syntax

Comment: Do tell me does this solution solve your problem ?

Answer (score 0):

I have changed your function that you are using from optimize package , but the package fsolve and my function returns the same value after execution.

```
T = np.array([137, 145, 150, 152, 159, 160, 184])
Di = np.array([1, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 1])
r = 5.0
def lnL(mu, sigma):
    return np.log(sigma) - (1 / 2) * np.sum(Di * ((T - mu) / sigma) ** 2) + np.sum(1 - Di) * -r
sol = lnL(15.0, 258.0)
print(sol)
```

Comment: the aim of the function is to find the value (mu, sigma)using respective given variables,
 sol = fsolve (lnL, (15.0,258.0)) are initial guess ,  in above case you directly taken( mu, sigma) where it is not recommended,we need to find (optimize) optimize function to compute it

Comment: Yes ok i understood but there are some issues, when we providing two initial values then we have to return two things in `lnL` function, you returning one equation, and This is simple concept of maths if you want to find two unknown values then there should be two equation given. So go through your question and tell me the second equation, if you have solution of this question in your handbook so do share the picture.

Comment: Or provide complete book question

Comment: hi ali, i think u still not understand problem..from above pic what it states is to solve the equation...i think ur awere of fsolve function , what it does it solve non linear equation, with trial and error method and finds best values. fsolve function we need define some function  and initial guess https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html
in this equation challenging is two variables are in [list] so we need pass it the equation and then we need solve

Comment: Hey @DjhakL i understood your question, i am telling the solution of your error, when you pass two initial values in an fsolve function then the respected function `lnL` should return list of length 2 or return 2 things, as your error `Shape should be (2,) but it is (1,).` there is one return value so this need to be change into list of length 2 will be return in` lnL` function or 2 separate varaibles.

Comment: https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/57335/scipy.optimize.fsolve

Comment: If you want i can share the stack traceback,if you debug your program then you will understand that there should be two equation to return when we passing two initial values

Comment: Thanks Ali  can u solve the problem and share your solution

Comment: I am not properly able to solve your problem but i have found the mistake, which is we need a one more equation for it. or one unknown variable to solve this equation.